# addSubView to viewController.navigatorController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a viewController and I am trying to add a subview to it such that it will cover the whole screen, however this has a navigationController in it so that adding a subView always adds it below the navigation bar, is there a way to simulate a presentModalViewController in cases like this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why can't you present a modal view controller with `wantsFullScreenLayout` set to `YES`?

Comment: because I want to have my own custom animation other than the 4 animation that apple provides

Answer (score 2):

You can add the subview to the view controller and then hide the navigation controller from the top or you could still push it to the navigation controller and then just remove the navigation controller from the top again and then you could use pop to go back and forth.

the code to push a view controller is

```
if(!self.YOURVIEWCONTROLLER){
    self.YOURVIEWCONTROLLER  = [[YOURVIEWCONTROLLER alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOURVIEWCONTROLLER" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.YOURVIEWCONTROLLER animatedLYES];
```

and on the next NEXTView.m add

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

remember to create an instance of YOURVIEWCONTROLLER in the .h file. Or you could do a simple

```
[self.view addSubview:NEWVIEW];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

at least at bear minimum the line for making the navigationController hide is there.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall once having a similar problem, and I seem to recall the solution was to add the subview to the navigation controller (as the view controller is already a sub view of the navigation controller) rather than adding it to the view controller.

Comment: I'll have a dig through my old projects in the morning and see if I can find how I solved it.

Comment: This is how I solved it. From the main view: [self.navigationController.view addSubview:newUIView];

Answer (score 1):

I recently have similar problems and after spending 5 to 10 min I get the exact solution...

According to my solution I simply add my custom UIView to subview of navigationController.view

Like This :-

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:popOver];
```

popOver - Your custom UIView

Happy Codding :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could hide the navigation bar when you add the subview. I have a method on my ViewController that looks like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; 
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
[self.view addSubview:v];
```

When that code executes, my navigation bar disappears and a full screen red view replaces it.

Comment: well actually it did, but it would still add it under the navigation bar

Comment: What behavior do you see?  I just tried it and it worked.  The nav bar is gone and the subview that I added is full screen.

Comment: actually I have to do       [viewController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]; quite different like what you have, if I do what you have then it does nothing. ALso what I see is the navigationBar is missing, however the subview position is still below the navigation bar

Comment: Strange.  Are you sure you don't have `viewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden`? If you use that one, it repositions viewController.view so that when you add subviews the space where the nav bar was won't linger. [UINavigation Controller Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBarHidden)

Comment: hmm... I tried setting that up to YES and it doesn't work.. so what do you mean by I don't have?

Comment: I misread your comment and thought you said you didn't have a navigationBarHidden property. I update the answer with more code. I wired that code to a button, and when I press the button the nav bar goes away and I have a full screen red view. I tested it on iOS 4 and iOS 5.

Comment: weird... that still didn't even hide my navigationBar

Comment: I wonder if your animations are fouling things up. I've seen that sort of thing before.

Answer (score 0):

Add the view to the superview of the navigationController's view.

```
[navigationController.view.superview addSubview:viewController.view];
```